# Migrating an iCloud Store Locally With Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud

I have a fully built application that uses `Core Data` to store user entries. Everything is working well with that case. I have built iCloud synching into the app last year and that was working well, but recently I have discovered an issue after releasing an update (with no iCloud changes). Upon updating, the user’s data had disappeared from the application (though it still existed in iCloud).

The reason for the disappearance was that when I created the application, I used “`CloudLogs`” as the `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey`, but on every subsequent launch (including the upgrade), I used “`iCloud`” as the `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey`, for the options when creating the store. This was of course a mistake on my part, but until recently, this actually worked in my application. Again, a mistake on my part to use different stores.

So my task now is to migrate the “`CloudLogs`” and “`iCloud`” directory locally, back it up and then migrate to a new “`iCloudPermanent`” store, or whatever it’ll be called.

When creating my application,  I used      `NSURL *localURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@“MyApp.sqlite”];`. When I went over to iCloud, I didn’t change that to `MyAppiCloud.sqlite`; I simply just migrated the data with “`CloudLogs`” as the `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey` and “`APPCloud`” as the `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey`.

My question is: in order to do the migration, I’m thinking that I’ll back up the iCloud store, remove it, and then add it without the `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey`. Do I need to create a new `MyAppiCloud.sqlite` and use that? i.e so local without iCloud would use `MyApp.sqlite`, but the iCloud store would use `MyAppiCloud.sqlite` for the URL.

I don’t see the point of doing that. Can anyone confirm what’s the required purpose of using different `URLs`; one for local and one for iCloud? Couldn’t I just use the same, but with different `NSDictionary` options?

Comment: I use different file names so it's easy to tell whether the store is an iCloud store or whether its a local store.  Also if you are migrating to or from iCloud depending on the users preferences how will you do that using the same file ?  See sample apps here 
http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/

Comment: Dear @DuncanGroenewald - thanks so much for your reply. That paragraph alone was enough for me to understand the importance of having it. Also, with your excellent code, I was able to to piece together exactly what I required, for example with taking a backup before doing a migration from iCloud to Local. That's really helpful. Do you want to add an answer so I can accept it?